# PHP Convert Date Then JSON Encode

Tags: php, json

I've got the following MySQL query:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM my_table";
$result = mysql_db_query($DBname,$sql,$link) or die(mysql_error()); 

$rows = array();

while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$rows[] = $r;
 }

 print json_encode($rows);

?>
```

Which outputs the following JSON format:

```
 [
  {
   "id":"100",
   "due_date":"2010-08-24 10:00:36"
  }
 ]
```

My question is:  In my MySQL query, how would I be able to first convert/modify one row (in this case, the date),or rather, how would I modify my current query, using something like:

```
$date = strtotime($r['due_date']);
$new_date = date('j M', $date);
```

And then JSON encode the results, to return this instead:

```
[
 {
 "id":"100",
 "due_date":"24 Aug"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use MySQL's [`DATE_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) to do it.

```
SELECT id, DATE_FORMAT(due_date_field, "%e %b") as due_date FROM my_table;
```